# Substitute #defined value in macro

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2008, c-preprocessor

```
#define PACKAGE Package123
#define TEST_SUITE_NAME_PACKAGE(Suite,Package) Suite##_##Package
#define TEST_SUITE_NAME(Suite) TEST_SUITE_NAME_PACKAGE(Suite,PACKAGE)
#define SUITE_NAME TEST_SUITE_NAME(UtilitiesTest)
```

I want `SUITE_NAME` to evaluate to `UtilitiesTest_Package123`, but after many variations, I still get `UtilitiesTest_PACKAGE`.

Note: `SUITE_NAME` is to be used as an identifier, not a string. I messed around with `#` and `##` operators, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: This must be a dupe but I can't figure out what I'd search for!

Comment: Anything that delegates the PP concat.

Comment: Does this work? `Suite ## _ ## Package`

Comment: @alk I don't think it is, as I do _not_ want to stringify it?

Comment: @John, Same idea; it mentions concatenation as well.

Comment: @anthony-arnold no difference

Comment: @alk This question isn't about stringification. He's looking for how to expand to an identifier.

Comment: To make the point, taking the answer in the link, you can have a `#define TEST_SUITE_NAME_PACKAGE2(Suite,Package) Suite##_##Package` that the original passes everything along to. This can also be done by just using `BOOST_PP_CAT`.

Comment: Put an answer up then @chris! In a perfect world, boost and non-boost variants would be wonderful.

Comment: @John, Well, it's really all the answer was saying. Anyway, Boost's is just the standard `#define CAT2(a,b) a##b` and `#define CAT(a,b) CAT2(a,b)`. Personally, I find an "overloaded" one more useful, really. Line lengths build extremely quickly when you repeat the macro name a few times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preprocessor sometimes requires a surprising number of indirections:

```
#define PACKAGE Package123
#define PASTE(x,y) x##_##y
#define TEST_SUITE_NAME_PACKAGE(Suite,Package) PASTE(Suite,Package)
#define TEST_SUITE_NAME(Suite) TEST_SUITE_NAME_PACKAGE(Suite,PACKAGE)
#define SUITE_NAME TEST_SUITE_NAME(UtilitiesTest)
```

This `PASTE` approach is a common preprocessor trick for just this sort of situation.

Answer (score 0):

Just add another level of indirection

```
#define PACKAGE Package123
#define TEST_SUITE_NAME_PACKAGE(Suite,Package) Suite##_##Package
#define _TEST_SUITE_NAME_PACKAGE(Suite, PACKAGE) TEST_SUITE_NAME_PACKAGE(Suite,PACKAGE)
#define TEST_SUITE_NAME(Suite) _TEST_SUITE_NAME_PACKAGE(Suite,PACKAGE)
#define SUITE_NAME TEST_SUITE_NAME(UtilitiesTest)
```